# Can't find my syntax error in myqsli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using the code below  to bind parameter in my query to add users to my DB

```
if($stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO tblusers(UserName,FirstName,LastName,Email,Password,RegistratieIP) VALUES( :username, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :ip)')){
    $stmt->bind_param(':username', $inUsername);
    $stmt->bind_param(':firstname', $inFirstName);
    $stmt->bind_param(':lastname', $inLastName);
    $stmt->bind_param(':email', $inEmail);
    $stmt->bind_param(':password', $inPassword);
    $stmt->bind_param(':ip', $ip);

    $stmt->execute();
}else{
    echo $dbh->error;
}
```

The error I receive is:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':username, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :ip)' at line 1a

I've been checking out the php manual and according to that manual, my syntax should be correct.

Comment: MySQLi does not support named parameters. Use `?` for your parameters and bind them using `$stmt->bind_param('s', $string);` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PHP `mysqli::prepare` page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) doesn't seem to agree with you. It uses `?` for parameter markers and the first argument to `bind` is the argument type rather than name.

Try instead with the form:

```
if ($stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl(col1,col2) values (?,?)')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $colval1, $colval2);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: I've done what you said and now I get:
mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

I've counted my parameters and my binds and they match

Comment: Okay, this worked. followed your advice before your edit. Now Everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try binding like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO tblusers(UserName,FirstName,LastName,Email,Password,RegistratieIP) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')){
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $inUsername, $inFirstName, $inLastName, $inEmail, $inPassword, $ip);
$stmt->execute();
```

Take a look at the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php